# SQL server primary key

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

In SQL server when I create database, and all tables primary keys are named "id", and then when go to management studio PANE viev, and open all tables there is always the first (by alphabet from object explorer) table primary key connected with all other primary keys.
I tried to rename primary keys then i dont have that relations but i need name id keys becouse of framework, 
Does anybody else had that kind of problem.
Is it some bug in SQL server.

i created tables using SQL management studio. ->new table->
i tryed on 2 computers, and same thing.

Comment: How did you create your tables? Manually using SQL statements or using a specialized tool to "draw" tables and relations?

Comment: i created tables using SQL management studio. ->new table->

Comment: Sorry, I'm having problems figuring out what your actual problem is from the question. (What's the "PANE view"?)

Comment: in PANE view, for creating queries, there are tables with their true relations. and there are shown relation from first table id to all other id. when i remove first table, second table's primary key connects to all other id's..

Comment: problem is what there are shown relation that i didn't create

Comment: Can you add a link to a screenshot of what you are describing?

Comment: screenshot: http://i63.tinypic.com/2i6j3ty.png , here i have a relation from id to id, wich i didn't create.